# I2C Connection BPi and Arduino

Tags: python, arduino, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, i2c

recently I have an on-going project on IoT involving communication between Arduino Devices with a berry board called Banana Pi. I noticed there are lots of similar topics out there but none of them discuss specifically how to set up the i2c driver and pins in Banana Pi since it is not a straight forward to install the library and start coding.

Here is my setup:

- Banana Pi

  1. I installed `Linux bananapi 3.4.104-bananian #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Apr 6 18:25:40 UTC 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux` on the Pi itself
  2. I installed required libraries and packages `apt-get install python-smbus python-dev i2c-tools`
  3. I followed other setup requirements (adding `i2c-dev` to `/etc/modules`, some `dtparams` to `/boot/config` albeit Linux bananapi doesn't initially have that file like the raspberry counterpart) from https://radiostud.io/howto-i2c-communication-rpi/
  4. Unlike its Raspbian counterpart, Linux BananaPi doesn't have option to activate I2C device from `sudo raspi-config` interfacing option. Therefore I skip this step.
  5. I coded simple implementation to display the message I received from Arduino

```
import smbus
from time import sleep

def main():
    SLAVE_ADDRESS = 0x04
    DATA_LENGTH = 4

    I2CBus = smbus.SMBus(1)
    print('initiated i2c connection as master')

    while True:
        try:
            message = I2CBus.read_i2c_block_data(SLAVE_ADDRESS, 0x00, DATA_LENGTH)
            print(message)
            sleep(1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Question: Every time I run the above code it returns: **

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "index.py", line 20, in <module>
    main()
  File "index.py", line 13, in main
    message = I2CBus.read_i2c_block_data(SLAVE_ADDRESS, 0x00, DATA_LENGTH)
IOError: [Errno 70] Communication error on send
```

which makes me think something is not right on step no 2 and 3 above. Some folks ask to modify the kernel as stated here http://forum.banana-pi.org/t/has-anyone-added-an-rtc/5004/5. However, the steps and their confidence are not clear with some other folks saying the GPIO pin to become unusable upon modifying the kernel, which I won't risk wasting time reflashing the memory back to its original OS, etc. to gain the GPIO functionality back.

- Arduino

  I use Arduino Due as the slave device to Banana Pi in this I2C communication. Cabling is simply connecting Arduino SDA to Pi's SDA and Arduino SCL to PI's SCL (both devices operate at 3.3V) with grounds connected to each other as well.
  Did some coding on the Arduino side again following https://radiostud.io/howto-i2c-communication-rpi/ with a simple modification to send everything it receives from the serial monitor to the BPi. But since the error showed above I don't think that matters in this question

Your help is very appreciated due to the lack of proper resource